# using google_translate_element script in react shows this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'L'), Script error

Tags: reactjs

`useEffect(() => { var addScript = document.createElement("script"); addScript.setAttribute( "src", "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" ); document.body.appendChild(addScript); window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit; }, []);`

switching browser with another application or switching tabs make this error. if i use this directly inside 'index.html' then its work. any solution?